# how to use const array instead of const variable?

Tags: php, arrays, function, class, constants

hi my current function is something like this... i want to know how can i use `const apiKey` as array. and how can i use `'key'=> self::apiKey` as `'key'=> self::apiKey[rand(0,1)]` etc. Please help me in it.

```
const apiKey = 'api_key_ods000doo123';
public function counter_params($video_ID, $part) {
$params = array(
'id' => $video_ID,
'key' => self::apiKey,
'part' => $part
);
$result = self::Connect($params);
//print_r($params);
return $result;
}
```

Comment: So define your const as array.

Comment: it is giving error....

Comment: Post the error you're getting, then. We can't help without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: What's your PHP version? Seems like I remember const arrays not always being available...

Comment: what to write here `'key' => self::apiKey,` to randomize the values ?

Comment: @Don'tPanic  Const arrays available since php5.6

Comment: Fatal error: Arrays are not allowed in class constants

Comment: So... what's your PHP version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my php version is old, this is why i have used this code

```
define('randomize_api' , serialize(array('AIzaSyBhl0bx7Psf5LKUhboBvtTTufSxXO1PO1s','AIzaSyD8rmarWEJyQwxMqNuFHLQ5E5tcgi4BD10')));
$avv = unserialize(randomize_api);
$bss =  $avv[rand(0,count($avv)-1)];
define('randomize_value_api' , $bss );
```

and `const apiKey` this inside class, i simply assign 
`const apiKey = randomize_value_api;`

i know long way,, it can be shorter but i used it for my convenient..

Answer (score 2):

Just define the constant as an array (requires PHP >= 5.6.0):

```
const apiKey = array('api_key_ods000doo123', 'api_key_ods000doo456'); //etc...
```

Then access a random one with a random number from 0 to the last index:

```
'key'=> self::apiKey[rand(0,count(self::apiKey)-1)],
```

Or use a built-in function:

```
'key'=> self::apiKey[array_rand(self::apiKey)],
```

Or if you want `key` to be a randomized array:

```
shuffle(self::apiKey);
```

Then use what you've been using:

```
'key' => self::apiKey,
```

Comment: thanks but my php version didn't allowed me to use it.. :(